# How to specify a list of foreign keys in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

How can I specify with data annotation or fluentapi, a list of string in my model like a list of foreign keys? I know that I could specify the User model in the list, but I'd like to have a list of strings.

Model Example:

```
public class Allocation
{
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      ...
      public List<string> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
     [Key]
     public string Id { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even expert developers **FAIL MISERABLY** when it comes to Entity Framework, so I'll let you into a little secret. **Write the code you wish you had**.

With regards directly to your scenario, you're over complicating things unnecessarily. Let Entity Framework do it's job and handle the relationships for you!

All you should need to model this relationship is...

```
public class Allocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Allocation Allocation { get; set; }
}
```

Now please note that **I DID NOT write the code I wish I had**, but that's because the code I wish I had was overkill for this question, and very high-level. If you do however want to delve into this subject and find out  what Entity Framework really can do for you, I would start here...

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/02/04/strengthening-your-domain-a-primer/